# The Resistance: so close, and yet so far. Why? (in-universe explanation)

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

The Resistance eventually

> made it to Crait, but only after several hours of sub-light travel.  When they came out of hyperspace, we know then that it was within a radius of Crait of that many hours of top sub-light speed.

Even if the ships were travelling half the speed of light, they would've been really rather close to

> Crait, such that no other planetary destination (except perhaps another planet in the same system) could have possibly been their intended destination.

Why in the Star Wars universe did they jump

> so close to the planet rather than exiting right next to it.

(Out of universe, of course, this is in the same vein as Episode I's "it's pretty far, but I think we can make it").

Comment: Somewhat unrelated question: is it Crait, Krait, or Krayt? I see the first two used in this discussion, but I assumed it was the last one because of Krayt dragons.

Comment: @JustinLardinois - Crait.

Answer (score 20):

We know from the film's [Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary) that Crait was the fleet's *original* destination, somewhere so immensely desolate and distant that under normal cirumstances, it would be impossible for them to be found by anyone who didn't know where to look.

> *"THE LAST GASP of hope for the Resistance is the otherwise uninviting
>   mineral planet of Crait, tucked in a remote sector of the Outer Rim
>   Territories. **This has been Leia Organa and Amilyn Holdo's secret
>   endgame - bunkering down on a former rebel world that had fallen off
>   most modern starcharts.** The Resistance's penchant for using old
>   rebel-era caches and facilities is part of Leia's strategy, for she
>   alone has a store of navigational information from the early days of
>   the Rebellion that she has never shared."*

As to why they came out of hyperspace so far from the planet, there are a few possible explanations, all equally likely (and probably it's a combination of all three).

- The navigational data is decades old, which means that lining up with the planet on exit would be difficult. Better to come out early and travel at sublight for a few hours than risk hitting the planet head-on.
- An excess of caution. Better to come out in open space, scan the system ahead for signs of the First Order than come out near the planet into an ambush.
- The system lacks decent hyperspace exit points and in the absence of a mapping expedition, Leia uses the only safe, known hyperspace exit point in the Crait system.

Comment: It's frustrating because these are all feasible in-universe answers but we'll never know because the bloated script left no room for a single line of dialogue to clarify the situation.

Comment: @Rapscallion - It'll almost certainly be addressed in the novelisation/s

Comment: You're probably correct, but until it is addressed these are just out-of-universe rationalisations for a wonky plot. I don't mean to come across as disrespectful; I think your efforts to address these questions are admirable.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think Crait was their original destination: before they knew about the First Order's hyperspace-tracking capabilities, their intent was to jump to the middle of nowhere, so that the likelihood of someone accidentally finding them would be infinitesimal. They'd then be able to regroup, rest up a bit, and come up with a better plan for their next step.

(The visuals of that scene reinforce this idea: the Resistance ships appear in the middle of a totally uniform field of stars, no standout features whatsoever. So when the First Order ships appear shortly after, it's a total shock.)

*I don't think the Visual Dictionary quote is as clear-cut as Valorum makes it out to be: "end game" is not the same thing as "intended destination". When they made that jump, there's no indication that anyone thought they were getting to end-game levels of desperation.*

Comment: Sorry, but Crait was their original destination.

Comment: @Valorum: based on what?

Comment: Based on the Visual Dictionary description of Crait; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/176721/20774

Comment: I disagree with the idea that their intent was to jump into the middle of nowhere, but I also disagree that Crait was always their final destination. It makes strategic sense to jump within proximity of an old Rebel base, and to keep doing so just in case you have to hole up in an emergency, just as we witnessed. Just because it's their LAST GASP doesn't mean it was their FIRST IDEA.

Comment: @vynsane If it was in case of emergency, landing hours out was a demonstrably bad way to go about it :) Though it could definitely be the case, especially when combined with some of the other suggestions.

Comment: @vynsane - You can disagree with it all you like. That doesn't make it any less true :-)

Comment: @Valorum - truth, something something, point of view... the disagreement hinges on when that LAST GASP decision was formulated: before or after the jump into the vicinity of Crait. Unless TVD makes it clear that it was before the jump, then the truth is still up in the air.

Comment: @vynsane - Traveling at sublight their options for potential planets are basically nil unless they're actually aiming for something. On top of which, the planet is a former rebel base. It's all far too compelling to be a coincidence.

Comment: I never said it was a coincidence, just that it was not necessarily their intended final destination. I'm saying they probably jumped near Crait because they knew the base was there in case of an emergency. If there was no emergency, I don't see why they wouldn't have jumped again on their way to a better-provisioned base, along a prescribed route that would take them near multiple former Rebel outposts, possibly at least one provisioned with fuel. Remember, they only couldn't jump because they knew the FO would track them again, and they would be dead in the water that time.

Comment: I agree that {CK}ra{iy}t wasn't their destination; they just didn't choose their "middle of nowhere" at random. The planet was a contingency plan -- if it had been their intended goal all along, they would not have come out of hyperspace hours away from it.

Comment: @vynsane - They don't have a better provisioned base. They're on the run with the hounds of hell on their heels.

Comment: @Valorum I dislike that they make the movies canonically subpar compared to the associated literature. If incidental details are clarified in worldbooks and novelisations that's fine, but it seems to me that there's a trend now to be sloppy with the SW movies and just let the books clean them up. Do not like.

Comment: @curiousdannii - They do it on purpose. The films drive the books drive the comics drive the TV series. Each needs a reason for fans to buy them so they dribble extra canon facts out into each of them.

Comment: The entire plot doesn't make any sense, from why they jumped so far to the actual destination to the ridiculous chase. The Empire could have destroyed the fleet in a matter of minutes but for some misterious reason they decide to wait for it to run out of fuel?

Answer (score -1):

> The entire plot doesn't make any sense, from why they jumped so far to the actual destination to the ridiculous chase. The Empire could have destroyed the fleet in a matter of minutes but for some misterious reason they decide to wait for it to run out of fuel?

@algiogia The three provided scenarios above provide perfectly acceptable justification for the Resistance jump *near* and not *to* Crait - reasons that fall perfectly within the logic of the established Star Wars universe and are easy enough to assume with that pre-existing knowledge.

As for the reason the First Order did not destroy the Resistance outright en route, it's in dialogue. The Resistance ships are faster - enough to outpace the larger star destroyers in a sublight race. Also, consider that lasers' powers diminish over space traveled, just as a bullet loses height and velocity. Combine that distance factor with the fact that the Resistance ships still have shields, and it's clear why the First Order can do literally nothing but keep firing in hopes that the shields will eventually fail or their fuel tanks run dry. As for jumping ahead of them and cutting them off, there are reasons in the established universe as to why this is impossible, as well. This is definitely a Star Wars movie where a deeper knowledge of the universe pays off.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. Did you mean to make this a comment?